# AngularJS - Why does $scope.$apply affect other scopes

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app, I have 2 controllers which are not nested. Calling the $scope.$apply method seems to affect the other sibling scope as well.

In the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelvinyong/JY5sb/) below, it seems that the ControllerOne's {{doubleMe(x)}} expression is evaluated whenever ControllerTwo updates the clock every second. This can be shown from the console message.

I can understand why that expression is evaluated whenever the text input (on the same scope) changes, but why would $scope.$apply on another scope cause that expression to be re-evaluated as well?

Note that I could have avoided $scope.$apply by using $timeout, but the outcome is observed.

```
    <!-- HTML file -->
    <div ng-app>
        <h1>Root</h1>
        <div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
            <h2>Scope One</h2>
            1 * 2 =  {{doubleMe(1)}}<br/>
            2 * 2 =  {{doubleMe(2)}}<br/>
            3 * 2 =  {{doubleMe(3)}}<br/>
            <input ng-model="text">
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
            <h2>Scope Two</h2>
            {{clock.now | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

// js file

```
    function ControllerOne($scope) {
        var counter=1;
        $scope.doubleMe = function(input) {
            console.log(counter++);
            return input*2;
        }
        $scope.text = "Change Me";
    }

    function ControllerTwo($scope) {
        $scope.clock = {
            now: new Date()
        };

        var updateClock = function() {
            $scope.clock.now = new Date()
        };

        setInterval(function() {
            $scope.$apply(updateClock);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you can see `$scope.$apply = $rootScope.$digest //+ some error handling` and since `$scope.$apply` uses $rootScope it affects all its descendants.

so If you update a child scope, you can call `$scope.$digest` to dirty-check only that scope and its descendants and as a result you reduce the number of dirty-checks and increase your performance.

**Example**

I changed your code and added $digest.

```
setInterval(function() {
             $scope.clock.now = new Date();
            $scope.$digest();
        }, 1000);
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/JY5sb/4/

Comment: perhaps it is important to mention It is not always the best to use $digest . For example, consider the $digest() is happening in a scope that is a child of ng-repeat's scope where you want  to escalate the changes to higher scopes. it is true $digest performs better than $apply however it is not what we might want in most of the cases

Answer (score 0):

From the AngularJS docs in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7aef2d54e0a48fae18a289813f699962d8310565/src/ng/rootScope.js#L86)

> ```
>    * # Pseudo-Code of `$apply()`
>    * <pre>
>        function $apply(expr) {
>          try {
>            return $eval(expr);
>          } catch (e) {
>            $exceptionHandler(e);
>          } finally {
>            $root.$digest();
>          }
>        }
>    * </pre>
> ```

Alex is correct that if you just want to have your changes reflected in the current scope and its children, `scope.$digest()` is the thing to use. However, AngularJS often discourages this since expressions often have side-effects that modify global objects like services which can in turn modify sibling scopes.

Comment: you are also right, angular’s documentation favors $apply since it simpler to use $apply all the time and $apply has special error handling that $digest lacks, but for situations like this, the performance increase is much more important.

Comment: @AlexChoroshin -- I completely agree.